# Como criar link com hover mostrando traços dos lados

Tags: html, css, menu

## O que desejo fazer

Desejo criar um menu e para cada link eu desejo aplicar um efeito "hover". Quando o usuário passar o mouse serão mostrados traços aos lados do link.

## Exemplo em Imagem

Segue [aqui](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/913/PpsDZr.jpg) como eu estou tentando fazer. Quando eu passar o mouse em cima de "home" desejo que essas 2 linhas apareçam ao lado. Tentei usar o `<hr>` ou `<span>` e não obtive sucesso.

## O que eu já tentei

```
<li>
    <a href="" title="Home"><p><span>__</span>home</p></a>
</li>
```

Eu tentei colocar a tag span ao lado do p, mas o parágrafo ocupa 100 da largura, então ele ficava em outra linha, então tentei colocar esse span junto do parágrafo, ai ele fica coladinho, mas fica bem no "chão".

## Update

```
<li>
    <a href="" title="Home">
        <div class="traco"></div>
        <div class="textoMenu">home</div>
        <div class="traco"></div>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="" title="Empresa">
        <div class="traco"></div>
        <div class="textoMenu">a empresa</div>
        <div class="traco"></div>
</li>
```

### CSS

```
.traco {
    width: 20px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 8px;                            
}

.textoMenu{
    .colorFonte(@corTodasLetras);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 14px;
    .marginReduzida(0,10px);
    float: left;
}
```

Agora eu só preciso arranjar um modo de centralizar esses links.

Comment: Você pode criar esses traços, definindo `height` e `width` e deixar como `display:none`, aí quando você passa o mouse, só color `.classe:hover {display:block}`. se você tiver algo que já fez no JSFIDDLE só responder.

Comment: Bem Vindo ao SO-PT, allan, poderia postar o código do que você já tentou fazer, para podermos lhe ajudar mais facilmente.

Comment: @FelipeStoker Já tentei fazer assim, mas usando o span, e não deu certo. Pro span eu precisei inserir algo dentro da tag para essas propriedades serem aplicadas.

Comment: Tente `.classe:hover span` então.

Comment: @FelipeStoker coloquei um display:block e ficou assim: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/537/iA8Cww.jpg

Comment: Entendi, publiquei uma resposta, olha lá, se ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta do [Fernando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2998/fernando) está basicamente correta. Algumas propriedades foram adicionadas para permitir o ajuste do tamanho das linhas:

```
ul > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

    ul > li > a:hover::after {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        border-top: solid 1px black;
        width: 50px;
        height: 1px;
        top: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        right: 1px;
    }

    ul > li > a:hover::before {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        border-top: solid 1px black;
        width: 50px;
        height: 1px;
        top: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        left: -1px;
    }
```

[Aqui vai o JSFiddle com a simulação.](http://jsfiddle.net/uepa5924/2/)

Comment: muito obrigado ! Certinho ^^.

Answer (score 4):

Preparei uma versão em que você pode controlar várias caracteristicas do traço e dos outros elementos com CSS, para não ficar limitado à largura do "sinal de menos" ou de outros caracteres, e ter controle preciso sobre o design.

A  vantagem dessa solução é que você não precisa inserir nenhum caractere estranho no conteúdo do HTML, definitivamente separando o conteúdo do visual.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="traco"></span>
        <span class="link">HOME</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="traco"></span>
        <span class="link">CONTATO</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu a {
   display:block;
   position:relative;
   float:left;                       /* somente se o menu for horizontal */
   overflow:auto;
   text-decoration:none;
   color: #422;
   background-color: #422;
}

#menu a span.link {
   position:relative;
   display:block;
   margin: 0 20px;                   /* Largura do traço */
   padding: 0 4px;                   /* Espaço entre o traço e as letras */
   z-index: 10;
   color: #ffe;
   background-color: #422;
}

#menu a span.traco {
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   height: 50%;
   z-index: 5;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #422;   /* Espessura do traço */
}

#menu a:hover span.traco {
   border-color: #ffe;              /* Cor do traço */
}
```

> Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/pemyzmhm)**

Answer (score 2):

Eu resolveria esse problema utilizando [Pseudo Classes CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) e [Pseudo Elementos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover). Utilizando os pseudos: [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after), e [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

Criaria uma regra similar a essa:

```
ul > li > a:hover::after{    
    content : '-';
}

ul > li > a:hover::before{    
    content : '-';
}
```

E formataria os `content`, conforme necessário;

Acompanhe aqui um [exemplo online](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/uepa5924/1/).

[Exemplo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/uepa5924/1/), controlando a posicionamento do traço.

Para definir o tamanho da linha você pode adicionar mais "-", na propriedade `content`, e diminua o espaço entre as letras com a propriedade css [`letter-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing), fazendo um efeito de um traço continuo, é uma opção. Segue [aqui um exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/uepa5924/3/).

Comment: +1. Me parece a solução mais elegante e com menor impacto.

Comment: @OnoSendai Mas como poderia controlar o tamanho da linha ?

Comment: @allan Eu adicionei uma resposta que leva em consideração o tamanho da linha.

Comment: @allan, verifique a edição da resposta e meu novo exemplo de traço continuo.

Answer (score 1):

Entendi, pelo que vi, você vai ter que ter dois traços mesmo, pode ser com float:left, algo assim:

```
<div class="traco"></div>
<div class="divDomeio"></div>
<div class="traco"></div>
```

Não use o span crie uma classe nova.

Comment: Blz, ficou certinho. Coloquei-os dentro do <a>, agora é pensar em como poderia alinhar esse link no centro.

Comment: use `text-align:center`, ou coloque o seu HTML aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer com espaços e `line-through` no `hover`, assim:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="" title="Home"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>home<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
a span {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

a:hover span {
    text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/9r2xtj7z/)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, agradeço a todos os que se despuseram a ajudar-me. Escolhei a resposta do **@OnoSendai** usando os pseudo-elementos.

## Código

### CSS

```
ul > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

ul > li > a:hover::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 1px;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
}

ul > li > a:hover::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 1px;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="" title="Home">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="A Empresa">a empresa</a></li>
</ul>
```